# Unable to include header files in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans

In netbeans I am creating a new folder and adding header files to it.

Now when I include the header file within the newly created folder to another file by using:

```
#include "folder1/myheaderFile.h"
```

The compiler complains that it is unable to find the header file.

The error is:

```
main.cpp:31:39: fatal error: folder1/myheaderFile.h: No such file or directory
```

Is there some way out as I want to include the header files within a folder in my #include?

EDIT: Do i need to make a makefile for every folder? 
Another EDIT:

```
When I right clicked on the error its showing
unresolved directive
#include
Analyzed system include paths:
/usr/include/C++/4.6
/usr/include/C++/4.6/x84_64_linux_gnu
/usr/include/C++/4.6/backward
/usr/lib/gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

Comment: Does 'folder1' relate to an actual folder on disk in the same folder as the cpp file, or just some reference in the IDE?

Comment: @learnvst It relates to an actual folder..I have checked it.

Comment: @learnvst Although the folder exists on disk...yet the name of the folder is not appearing in my project window

Comment: Which platform ? Are you including in your Search Path that folder ? #include "folder/header.h" presumes your root/project hierarchy starting from ".". Also, the including path may have to traverse back, i.e: "../folder/header.h"

Comment: @Alex Thanks for replying. How do I check the search path within netbeans

Comment: Is your filesystem case-sensitive?

Comment: It depends, I assume somewhere in your project configuration. But still, bear in mind that if you use absolute paths you must make sure you are using them correctly. Have a look at this: http://zetcode.com/articles/netbeanscdevelopment/
Near the end it says about Including Directories

Comment: @SylvainDefresne How do I check that? Also i am using the same case letter...just as a precaution...thanks for replying :)

Comment: @KeiraShaw Try to create a file called `x.txt` and another called `X.txt` in the same directory. If this fail, then your filesystem is not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Alex Within general within Project Properties it is showing relative path of my project...thanks again for replying

Comment: 1) Are you including from a subdirectory? 2) Have you made sure the names are correct? 3) Do you have read access to the header file? 4) Are the extensions correct ? 5) What platform are you using, and what compiler ?

Comment: @Alex i am in ubuntu 12.10 and my compiler is gdb. 1. No i am not including from subdirectory 2. yes I have cross checked 3. yes i have read access to header file. One more thing..netbeans is showing..ignore folder pattern "^(nbproject|build|test|tests)$" Thanks again for replying :)

Comment: Have you tried a full path? Out of curiosity, what happens if you do: #include "/home/user/project/folder/header.h" ? Substitute path as necessary. My guess is you're not setting the search path properly.

Comment: @Alex Yes I tried it right now only. But this too does not seem to work..its still complaining..thanks again for replying :)

Comment: @Alex I guess u r nailing it the right way. When I right clicked on the error its showing..I have written that in Another Edit in my post. Please have a look at it. But I am still not getting as to how should I rectify it.

Comment: The include files you have specified are for system-wide headers. Is the header you are including yours or downloaded/installed ? Do you see the path of the header in the output ? If you are including the header which is in a folder, from another folder, then you need to traverse back, i.e: #include "../folder/header.h". If this is a system folder, such as the ones residing in /usr/local/include in my system, all you have to do is #include <header.h> or if it resides in a sub-folder (quite often), #include <Libname/header.h>. As long as you have set the include paths properly it should work.

Comment: What's the path of the header you are including, and what's the path of the file that is including the header ?

Comment: @Alex Thanks you really helped a lot :). In case you put ur answer in the Answers..i'll accept it. Right now I dont have the points to upvote. Thanks. One of my friends have another trouble..hope u'll help her too. The question is there at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968730/add-library-to-existing-project-netbeans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's for your convenience:

The include file paths you have specified are for system-wide headers. Is the header you are including yours or downloaded/installed system-wide? Do you see the path of the header in the output? 
If you are including the header which is in a folder, from another folder, then you need to traverse back, i.e: `#include "../folder/header.h"`

If this is a system folder, such as the ones residing in /usr/local/include in my system, all you have to do is

```
#include <header.h>
```

or if it resides in a sub-folder (quite often),

```
#include <Libname/header.h>
```

As long as you have set the include paths pointing at it, it should work.

To setup the include paths and directories, see example: http://zetcode.com/articles/netbeanscdevelopment/ near the end of the page.

Remember that when you hardcode paths, you need to take into consideration the current path of the file which is including the header.

Alternatively, you can use cmake & make (don't know what Netbeans uses), where you define everything your self.

You can test with full path, i.e:

```
#include "/home/user/project/folder/header.h
```

or you can test from command line and set the include path.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the great effort and help :)